# How to delete Kubernetes job automatically after job completion

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a kubernetes job on GKE and want to delete the job automatically after the job is completed.

Here is my configuration file for the job.
I set `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 0` but the job was not deleted automatically.
Am I missing something?

- cluster / node version: 1.12.8-gke.10

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  # automatically clean up finished job
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myjob
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myjob
          image: gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT/myimage:COMMIT_SHA
          command: ["bash"]
          args: ["deploy.sh"]
      # Do not restart containers after they exit
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this feature is still not available on GKE now.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alpha-clusters#about_feature_stages

```
To ensure stability and production quality, normal GKE clusters only enable features that
are beta or higher. Alpha features are not enabled on normal clusters because they are not
production-ready or upgradeable.
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how did you create job.

If you are using CronJob you can use `spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` and set values to 0. It will say K8s to not sotre any previously finished jobs.

If you are creating pods using YAMLs you have to deleted it manually. However you can also set CronJob to execute command each 5 minutes.

```
kubectl delete job $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}')
```

It will delete all jobs with status succeded.

Answer (score -2):

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jp-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "delete"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jp-runner
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-jp-runner
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: jp-runner
  apiGroup: ""
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-jp-runner
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: clean-jobs
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-jp-runner
          containers:
          - name: clean-jobs
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl delete jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}')
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 0
```